# Reduce dimension of Docker Python Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm building a Python Image in Docker and I need it to be the smaller possible.

I'm using venv on my PC and the app is basically a unqiue file .py of 3.2kb. I'm using Python 3.10 and the following libraries

```
import feedparser
import sched
import time
import dbm
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import logging
```

My current Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.10.9-alpine3.17

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.py ./
COPY *.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

CMD ["./main.py"]
```

And the final image is about 60Mb. Now, I'm seeing that Python Alpine image is about 20/30Mb and the folder containing my project is about 22Mb.

Is there a way to strip even more the dimension of the Docker Image I'm creating, maybe clearing cache after the building or installing only the necessary package?

Comment: 60 MB doesn't seem "large" for a Docker image.  If you do think there's 22 MB in the image's `/app` directory, the only things you copy in are Python and plain-text files; do you know how big those are?  Is it possible the bulk of the space is coming from the installed library stack?

Comment: @DavidMaze definitely not large but, because I'm going to run into an environment that is very limited in storage availability, every Mb matters. Yes, as explained the only files I'm copying are the `main.py` file and the `requirements.txt`. So, besides them, I'm not adding files to the image. On another note, the folder of my project includes indexing data from PyCharm as well as cache and other stuff, and they are NOT copied into the new Docker image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purge the cache:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && pip cache purge
```

Additionally there are some bundled wheel files for bootstrapping [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) in the alpine image which are useless, since pip/setuptools are already installed. If you don't need to create venvs within the container, you could unlink those wheels and save another ~3.3 MB:

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.10.9-alpine3.17 ls -l '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ensurepip/_bundled/'     
total 3212
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Dec  8 01:27 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec  8 01:27 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       2051534 Dec  8 01:27 pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       1232695 Dec  8 01:27 setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: when I should run the command? After my `docker build` command?

Comment: It should be written into the Dockerfile so that it happens during a docker build.

Comment: yes, I understand that but, I mean, the `docker run --rm -it`, etc. I run it before launching `docker build` to create my Image, is it correct?

Comment: Not correct. With that command, I'm just demonstrating where in the `python:3.10.9-alpine3.17` image the files you may want to unlink are. You can rm them in your Dockerfile, if you want to shave another 3.3 MB off.

Answer (score 2):

In your `pip` command, add the `--no-cache-dir` flag to disable writing files to a cache:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```